# how to properly send JSON via ajax to c# [WebMethod]?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

I want to send a JSON string via ajax to `[WebMethod]`. My JSON values contain double quotation marks (`"`). In js, I create an object and convert it to JSON with `JSON.stringify(my_object)`. Console shows properly formatted JSON (double quotes are masked with `\`), [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) confirms it.

But the problem appears in `[WebMethod]`. After hours of debugging I found out that it ignores masked `"` and treats them as normal `"`. So my properly JSON-formatted string becomes not properly JSON-formatted string.

Is there a way to fix this? Changing my input string is not an option (I mustn't get rid of `"`).

Here's some code:

ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Test_Page.aspx/Test',
    data: "{json: '" + JSON.stringify(json_string) + "'}",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {},
    error: function (msg) {}
});
```

web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Test(string json) {
    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Other_Function(json));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Test_Page.aspx/Test',
    data: JSON.stringify({json: json_string}),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {},
    error: function (msg) {}
});
```

Comment: almost, I had to stringify my `json_string`: `data: JSON.stringify({json: JSON.stringify(json_string)})`. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) It's just the way you pass it. I think the result should be the same if you do it like this, for example: JSON.stringify({json: ' "test" '})